# intel xdk build not like the emulator

Tags: javascript, jquery

hellow i got ta problem with intel xdk,i create an apps for detect a network on emulator and remote its work but when i try to build to apk.its not workking 
here the code :
on emulator and remote its work perfectly but when build its just say tidak ada (which mean no internet detected in this case i already put the network on)

```
function doesConnectionExist() 
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var file = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/MS-Arc-Mouse.jpg";
    var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 10000);

    xhr.open('HEAD', file + "?rand=" + randomNum, false);

    try {
        xhr.send();

        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 304) 
        {
        alert("Internet ON");
            PostDB();
            return true;
        } else {
        alert("tidak ada");
            return false;
        }
    } catch (e) {
    alert("tidak ada catch");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems highly likely that your code is not working properly in either environment. The response to your `XMLHttpRequest` is asynchronous, but you are trying to handle it synchronously. It's not clear why the two environments should give different behaviour but you can only address that issue, if it persists, once the asynchronism is fixed.

Comment: what make me confuse is when remote and debug using xdk cloud sevice this code work fine,but like i said when i try to build it into apk the code become wrong.